# Query in MySql returns a row, but my php code doesn't

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm stuck with this dumb problem. This code should show one row from 'miejscowosci' table, but it seems like it returns nothing, althaught the query works properly on myadmin.

```
$this->db = new mysqli(SRV, USR, PASS, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT reg FROM miejscowosci WHERE nazwa = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->store_result())
{
    echo $stmt->num_rows; //this echoes 0
}
$stmt->bind_result($this->region);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $this->region; //this echoes nothing
}
```

The query without WHERE clause gives a right output.

Comment: where is your `$city` set? I think that's your issue, you're trying to select region where city is empty, which doesn't exist. Try `$city='something that exists in your database'` just before the bind_param this should return results

Comment: :( $city is a parameter in that function and it is defined. Moreover changing above query to `"SELECT reg FROM miejscowosci WHERE nazwa = 'sth_that_exists_in_db'"` gave the same result.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, maybe the data is in your database is a bit screwed. maybe there are spaces before the city name or after the city name causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it appears that the problem was encoding and I solved it by adding `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` or uncommenting `collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci` and  `character_set_server=utf8` in php.ini.